# mysql query in vs mysql inner join

Tags: mysql

Could any one tell me which query would be faster and why?

```
(1) select * from userInfo where id in (select id from user)

(2) select a.* from userInfo a,user b where a.id = b.id
```

These are two big tables with 100 million records, I tried it, the (2) query is faster, but I don't know why? Thanks!

Comment: @DipenShah No, it's not a duplicate of that.

Comment: (it's probably a duplicate of something, however)

Comment: @Barmar Misread it. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

A join (implicit or explicit) will be faster most of times (specially if the involved columns are properly indexed).

That's because the `IN` expression is evaluated once for every row. So, if you have a large dataset inside the `IN` expression, it will be a *very*  expensive thing to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually the two queries are equivalent. But MySQL's query planner is not very good at optimizing `WHERE x in (SELECT ...)`. If you look at the `EXPLAIN` output, you'll see that the first query works by scanning the entire `userInfo` table, and then testing each `id` against the index in the `user` table, which will be slow if `userInfo` is much larger than `user`.